# Is it possible to have working OnClick event for TGlyph in FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I just put an instance of TGlyph on a FMX Form and tested this code.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Glyph1.OnClick:=myClick;  
end;

procedure TForm1.myClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('test');
end;
```

Nothing happening when I click the glyph. I know that there is no OnClick event for TGlyph in the Designer IDE. But this TGlyph has derived from TControl which has OnClick. I know that I can use TImage instead of TGlyph but I am just curiuse about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set

```
Glyph1.HitTest := true;
```

to make it work.